# Can an Azure container with a blob that has a snapshot be deleted?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, snapshot

I know that an Azure blob with snapshots cannot be deleted until all the snapshots are deleted.  Would it be possible, though, to delete the container that houses the blob (and, by extension, that blob too)?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem deleting a non-empty container, as long as there's no lease on the container or content within the container (e.g. a vhd in use as a disk for  VM).

Not sure which SDK you're using (or just raw REST) but... pretty trivial in node.js. Assuming you created a container called `deleteme` and uploaded a few blobs to it:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage')
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService();
blobSvc.deleteContainer('deleteme', function(error, result, response){
    if(!error){
      console.log('deleted')
    }
    else {
        console.log('not deleted')
    }
});
```

Note the use of `deleteContainer()`. Once deleted, this call will fail. However, you can use `deleteContainerIfExists()` which should continue to work even if the container is no longer there.

Also note: this works even if blobs within the container have snapshots.